# load yaml files from outside current directory

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

I want to load a `yaml` file from outside the working directory. I use `c++`. I used `YAML::LoadFile("/home/example.yaml")` and it complains `YAML::BadFile`. Please let me know if there is any way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

`YAML::LoadFile` does nothing else than reading the file via `std::ifstream`. So your actual problem is that you cannot open the file at all in your application.

Check whether the file exists and has the proper permissions so that your application may open it. Try opening it directly with a `std::ifstream` and hand that over to `YAML::Load` so you can inspect the stream directly to see what error occurred.

Comment: I can open as well as read/write the yaml file as long as it is in the build folder of the package.

Comment: ok, now with ifstream and Load, I can read the file but if I write something, it is not reflecting in the original file. To be frank, if I read from anywhere outside, it is reading and then I keep the location of the file to write to, in the build  folder, it just writes only a small part which I modified in the file from that I read.

Comment: ok, it's fine now. I made a mistake in addressing the right path while trying to access from outside the directory.